# assembly load a program from a sector and return

Tags: assembly, x86, dos

I doing a System Programming Assignment but am facing a slight issue.

i have managed to to write my boot sector and able to call another sector which i have read using int 13 . All instruction execute and the code return to boot sector .

But i am unable to access my variable declared in the second sector to be used in the 2nd sector

here is the code

```
[bits 16]
[org 0x7c00]

mov ah,2  
mov al,1    ;Number of sectors to read
mov ch,0    ;Cylinder number (10 bit value; upper 2 bits in CL)
mov cl,2    ;Starting sector number
mov dh,0    ;Head number
mov dl,0    ;Drive number

mov bx,cs
mov es,bx
mov bx,here

int 13h

jc error

call here


error:
 mov ah,0eh
 mov al,'E'
 mov bl,7
 mov bh,0
 int 10h
 jmp $

exit:
 mov ah,0eh
 mov al,'F'
 mov bl,7
 mov bh,0
 int 10h
 jmp $

here:


jmp $




times 510 - ($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

Sector2.asm

```
[bits 16]

mov bx,cs
mov ds,bx

jmp start

msg db "Welcome to my OSD",0

start:

mov si,0
mov si,msg

mov ah,0eh
mov al,':'
int 10h

mov ah,0eh
mov al,[si] ;; HERE IS THE PROBLEM IT PRINTS GARBAGE 
int 10h
inc si
mov ah,0eh
mov al,[si]  ;; HERE IS THE PROBLEM IT PRINTS GARBAGE 
int 10h
inc si
mov ah,0eh
mov al,[si]  ;; HERE IS THE PROBLEM IT PRINTS GARBAGE 
int 10h


ret





times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0x0055
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for Nasm to calculate the correct address for `msg`, it needs to be told an `org` corresponding to where the code will actually be loaded. You seem to be loading it to "same segment" (presumably 0) and offset `here`. `here` is going to vary as your code changes. How about if you put the `here:` label at the very end - after the boot sig? Then it would be at a known offset -0x7E00 - and you could `org` your second file to that. I think that would work. If you really need to load your second sector right after the "working code", you'll have to calculate that offset and `org` your second file to that.